# Policy Handle<Exception> issues in conjunction with Refit package and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, refit

I have set up my Xamarin core project with a lot of the tips I read from [here](http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/).

I have a simple service that I'm using to see if an entered url for a server is valid:  IValidateUrlService

I'm trying to use the [Polly](https://github.com/michael-wolfenden/Polly) library to do something like this:

```
var request = new PingUrlRequest();
var validateUrlTask = apiService.UserInitiated.ValidateUrl(request);

var response = await Policy
    .Handle<ApiException>()
    .RetryAsync(retryCount: 5)
    .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        await validateUrlTask);

reachable = HandleServerResponse(response);
```

This works fine unless I get an Exception.  For instance, when I was getting an ApiException on one server I was testing against; the above code did not absorb the error!  It just threw the exception and crashed the program.  I could only get the code to work properly by doing this:

```
try
{
    var request = new PingUrlRequest();
    var validateUrlTask = apiService.UserInitiated.ValidateUrl(request);

    var response = await Policy
        .Handle<ApiException>()
        .RetryAsync(retryCount: 5)
        .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            await validateUrlTask);

    reachable = HandleServerResponse(response);
}
catch (ApiException e)
{
    Mvx.Trace(e.StackTrace);
}
```

But that doesn't feel correct... What's the point of having the Handle parameter up top if it doesn't do anything?  I have to be implementing this wrong!  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ApiException` is being thrown that means that Polly retried 5 times to execute your code and failed each time thus it all ended with `ApiException` and you need to handle it.

> What's the point of having the Handle parameter up top if it doesn't do anything?

*Handle* specifies which type of exception your policy should apply for so you used it appropriately.

> But that doesn't feel correct...

I use the same pattern as you did in 2 code snippet and it is ok imho.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok perfect!  I was assuming that the Handle would ultimately end up handling the Exception but that makes sense.  Thanks!